# Git pushing to remote origin—changes are not commited in origin, only visible after git stash

Tags: git, git-stash

On my local machine I have cloned a remote repo, made some changes, commited, then pushed back to the remote repo which has NOT been touched in any way in the meantime.

On the remote machine when I look in the remote repo, I don't see the changes I made. `git status` tells me that there are changes to be committed. When I look into the files, I do not see any of the changes I made. When I do `git stash` in the remote branch, I see the changes. So somehow git does not commit the pushed changes in the remote repo.

Could someone please explain the logic behind this to me and how I can circumvent this situation? Can I somehow push changes to the remote repo without having to `git stash`?

Thanks a lot for the clarifications!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are pushing into a a remote that has a checkout-out working copy you will not see the changes automatically.  `git` is pushing the changes into the *repository* (the `.git` directory).  If you want to update the associated working copy, you would need to implement the appropriate logic in the `post-update` hook.

In general, `git` won't even let you push to a remote with an associated working copy without explicit configuration...you would typically see an error along the lines of:

```
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error: 
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To /home/lars/repo1
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to '/home/lars/projects/administrivia/repo1'
```

Comment: To add to this, you should generally only push to repos that were made with `git init --bare`, and have everyone else pull from there. Or if you don't like that, just pull and never push. Pushing to non-bare repos is all weird and crappy.

Comment: http://sitaramc.github.com/concepts/bare.html

This is a very nice solution to my problem.

Comment: Could it be that this is a thing of older git versions? My workplace has git version 1.5.6.5, while on my Mac I run 1.7.4.4.